# How to chnage FirstOrDefault to Any for ICollection?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, linq

I have this

```
return FeatureBodyPartId.HasValue ? query.Where(x => x.Person.PersonFeatures.FirstOrDefault<PersonFeature>().BodyPartId == FeatureBodyPartId && x.Person.PersonFeatures.FirstOrDefault<PersonFeature>().IsActive) : query;
```

which used FirstOrDefault and I want to change it to Any, can someone help me with this???

Comment: Not simply `x.Person.PersonFeatures.Any(f => f.BodyPartId == FeatureBodypartId && f.IsActive)`?

Comment: Side note - using FirstOrDefault and then immediately accessing the result is asking for hard to debug NullReference exceptions. Just use First() if the result is always expected to be present.